# Bash script does nothing when I run it, seems to keep waiting

Tags: bash, awk

I've written my first script, one in which I want to know if 2 files have the same values in a specific column.

Both files are WEKA machine-learning prediction outputs for different algorithms, hence they have to be in the same format, but the prediction column would be different.

Here's the code I've written based on the tutorial presented in https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners:

```
#!/bin/bash

lineasdel1=$(wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}')
lineasdel2=$(wc -l $2 | awk '{print $1}')
    if [ "$lineasdel1" != "$lineasdel2" ]; then
        echo "Files $1 and $2 have different number of lines, unable to perform"
        exit 1
    fi

function quitalineasraras {
    awk '$1!="==="&&NF>0'
}

function acomodo {
    awk '{gsub(/^ +| +$/, ""); gsub(/ +0/, " W 0"); gsub(/ +1$/, " W 1"); gsub(/ +/, "\t") gsub(/\+\tW/, "+"); print}'
}

function procesodel1 { 
    quitalineasraras "$1" | acomodo
}

function procesodel2 { 
    quitalineasraras "$2" | acomodo
}

el1procesado=$(procesodel1) 
el2procesado=$(procesodel2)

function pegar {
    paste <(echo "$el1procesado") <(echo "$el2procesado")
}

function contarintersec { 
    awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} $3==$8 {n++} END {print n}'
 }

unido=$(pegar)
interseccion=$(contarintersec $unido)

echo "Estos 2 archivos tienen $interseccion coincidencias."
```

I ran all individual codes of all functions in the terminal and verified they work successfully (I'm using Linux Mint 19.2). Script's permissions also have been changed to make it executable. Paste command also is supposed to work with that variable syntax.

But when I run it via:

`./script.sh file1 file2`

if both files have the same number of lines, and I press enter, no output is obtained; instead, the terminal opens an empty line with cursor waiting for something. In order to write another command, I've got to press CTRL+C.

If both files have different number of lines the error message prints successfully, so I think the problem has something to do with the functions, with the fact that awk has different syntax for some chores, or with turning the output of functions into variables.

I know that I'm missing something, but can't come up with what could be.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect some of your `awk` invocations are waiting for input they're not getting.

Comment: `if 2 files have the same values in a specific column` -  please post example input files and if they columns are the same or not. Such comparision sounds like a job for a single short awk script.

Comment: Consider adding `if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then printf "usage: %s file1 file1\n" "${0##*/}"; exit 1; fi` to the top of your script to ensure at least 2-arguments are given. (you can also negate the test with `'-s'` to ensure each file is non-empty)

Comment: I would like to request you to please post samples of your input and expected output in your question so that we will get complete requirement. I am pretty sure this could be done with a easy manner too, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> what could be.

```
function quitalineasraras {
    awk '$1!="==="&&NF>0'
}
function procesodel1 { 
    quitalineasraras "$1" | acomodo
}
el1procesado=$(procesodel1)
```

The positional variables `$1` are set for each function separately. The `"$1"` inside `procesodel1` expands to empty. The `quitalineasraras` is passed one empty argument `""`.

The `awk` inside `quitalineasraras` is passed only the script without the filename, so it reads the input for standard input, ie. it waits for the input on standard input.

The `awk` inside `quitalineasraras` without any file arguments makes your script seem to wait.